# Android PrintJob class public boolean start ()

Tags: android

I am using the new KitKat print service class PrintJob in a Android application. The documentation is showing 'public boolean  start ()'  function but when I try to include it in the application the function is not defined for the class. The code completion helper also does not have the function listed.

The import I am using is 'import android.printservice.PrintJob;' code is

```
            android.print.PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, new            ReceiptsPrintDocumentAdapter(), null);
```

and the line that will not compile is
                printJob.start();

The Android SDK is up to date. Does anyone know why ?

```
                          Bob H
```

Comment: target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:19 in project.properties and <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" /> in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, set the appropriate [minSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Then, in the root directory of your project, there'd be a file called `project.properties` . Open it, and edit the `target` value. Set it to `android-<your-api-level>`

Clean, rebuild.

Alternately, you can change the API level from GUI.

*Right-click on your project > Click Properties > Android > Select the API level for Kitkat*

For Kitkat 4.4, API Level should be 19.

Comment: The API levels are correct in project.properies and the API level is set to  19. The appropriate *.jar's are linked in with API 4.2.2.

Comment: Did you try the GUI method I‘ve mentioned?

Comment: Yes the API is at 19 and the SDK is at 4.2.2.

Comment: Yes the API is at 19 - 4.4.2. I tried both the regular API and the Google Maps API. Neither of the APIs had the start() function defined for the PrintJob class.